# parse json from kinesis firehose

Tags: json, go, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Hi I'm trying using kinesis firehose with S3. And I tried to read those s3 files. I'm using GO to read it.

However, I can't parse the JSON because the values are only appending without any delimiter.

here's the example of the file (note that the original input is appending to each other, I split them by a newline for formatting purposes):

```
{"ticker_symbol":"PLM","sector":"FINANCIAL","change":-0.16,"price":19.99}
{"ticker_symbol":"AZL","sector":"HEALTHCARE","change":-0.78,"price":16.51}
{"ticker_symbol":"IOP","sector":"TECHNOLOGY","change":-1.98,"price":121.88}
{"ticker_symbol":"VVY","sector":"HEALTHCARE","change":-0.56,"price":47.62}
{"ticker_symbol":"BFH","sector":"RETAIL","change":0.74,"price":16.61}
{"ticker_symbol":"WAS","sector":"RETAIL","change":-0.6,"price":16.72}
```

my question is, how can I parse it in Go? one solution that I can think of is to split them by `}{` and append them again. But it's pretty hackish.

Or does kinesis firehose provides delimiter?

***------UPDATE------***

currently I have implemented the solution with replacing all `}{` with `},{` and then add `[` at the beginning and `]` at the end. Then parse it.

However I'm still looking for alternatives as this solution would restrict any `}{` in the content of the json object

Comment: The value of json is coming inside a loop in which you are appending to create whole json. Please post the function which is creating the json.

Comment: It's coming from `aws kinesis firehose`. I use the sample data provided there which is basically a json object.

Comment: See if it is coming everytime you hit the api you a get a new row of json object then you should create a slice of result struct and then append to it one bye one. If it is coming after appending like this then you have to sue strings package to add delimiter to the end of each row. Please post the link of firehose example.

Comment: Yeah that's the thing.. It's a batch operation and I don't think it's a row based. I only make it like that to nicely format it in stack overflow. The original data is a single line string

Comment: that's good then It is quite easy for you to manage that then using slice.

Comment: how? one example is like this `{"ticker_symbol":"PLM"}{"ticker_symbol":"AZL"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a simple struct to unmarshal the json which is coming in batches. So each batch json is unmarshalled in to a json object. Then create a slice of structs to append the parsed json into the slice. This will append you result json all in slice of struct.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Ticker struct {
    TickerSymbol string  `json:"ticker_symbol"`
    Sector       string  `json:"sector"`
    Change       float64 `json:"change"`
    Price        float64 `json:"price"`
}

var jsonBytes = []byte(`{"ticker_symbol":"PLM","sector":"FINANCIAL","change":-0.16,"price":19.99}`)

func main() {
    var singleResult Ticker
    var result []Ticker
    if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBytes, &singleResult); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    if len(result) == 0 {
        result = append(result, singleResult)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", result)
}
```

**Edited:**

If the data is coming in batch which contains json objects appended to each other than you can go for regex expression to replace `}` with `},` and then trim right most `,` to make a valid json array of objects as:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

type Ticker struct {
    TickerSymbol string  `json:"ticker_symbol"`
    Sector       string  `json:"sector"`
    Change       float64 `json:"change"`
    Price        float64 `json:"price"`
}

var str = `{"ticker_symbol":"PLM","sector":"FINANCIAL","change":-0.16,"price":19.99}
{"ticker_symbol":"AZL","sector":"HEALTHCARE","change":-0.78,"price":16.51}
{"ticker_symbol":"IOP","sector":"TECHNOLOGY","change":-1.98,"price":121.88}
{"ticker_symbol":"VVY","sector":"HEALTHCARE","change":-0.56,"price":47.62}
{"ticker_symbol":"BFH","sector":"RETAIL","change":0.74,"price":16.61}
{"ticker_symbol":"WAS","sector":"RETAIL","change":-0.6,"price":16.72}`

func main() {

    r := regexp.MustCompile("}")
    output := strings.TrimRight(r.ReplaceAllString(str, "},"), ",")
    output = fmt.Sprintf("[%s]", output)
    fmt.Println(output)
}
```

Using `r := regexp.MustCompile("}")` will help you not to worry about whitespaces in between `}{`  which will interfere in replacing the string. So just replace `}` with `},` and then trim right.

Also The reason I am using MustCompile is:

> When creating constants with regular expressions you can use the
>   MustCompile variation of Compile. A plain Compile won’t work for
>   constants because it has 2 return values.

Full Working code with json parse on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fcSV1UmUnlv)

Comment: the string is not individual and always comes in batch. How can I split them into individual json?

Comment: @kkesley ok the string comes with all json objects at once.

Comment: yes.. currently I have implemented the solution with replacing all `}{` with `},{` and then add `[` at the beginning and `]` at the end. Then parse it. However I'm still looking for alternatives as this solution would restrict any `}{` in the content of the json object

Comment: @kkesley Please check edited code with full example on Go Playground link.